# Yii params condition ( PHP Framework )

Tags: php, yii

I am a complete newbie in the world of yii and doing my best to learn the framework as best as I can, while reading the book on Yii - '**Web Application Development Using Yii and PHP**' by *Jeffrey Winesett*,

I came across :

```
'params'=>array(':projectId'=>$this->_project->id)
```

If anyone has read the book, can someone explain why do we use *:projectId* why not directly *projectId*? **What does the ':' stand for?** Is it the specific syntax or is it something php specific.

This was the exact code :

```
public function actionIndex()
    {

        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Issue', array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                'condition'=>'project_id=:projectId',
                'params'=>array(':projectId'=>$this->_project->id),
            ),
        ));
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }
```

Any answer would be highly appreciated.
Regards.

Comment: Is it (this `params` array) being used in an SQL query for binding parameters?

Comment: This was the exact code 
public function actionIndex()
 {
  //$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Issue');
  $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Issue', array(
   'criteria'=>array(
     'condition'=>'project_id=:projectId',
     'params'=>array(':projectId'=>$this->_project->id),
    ),
  ));
  $this->render('index',array(
   'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
  ));
 }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ":" id there to identify param within the condition string. It's a way to safely bind params to an sql statement.

In your case, when you specify this condition

```
project_id=:projectId
```

In your db schema, Yii know that project_id is an integer, then when you bind the param with :

```
'params'=>array(':projectId'=>$this->_project->id),
```

Yii will make sure you bind an integer and write the SQL statement for it and generate SQL statement like this : `project_id=26`

This is the same thing for string ex.:

```
        'criteria'=>array(
            'condition'=>'name=:myname',
            'params'=>array(':myname' => 'Ronald McDonald'),
        ),
```

then your sql statement for this condition will be `name='Ronald McDonald'`

Comment: Is the binding using ':' specific to only Yii or is it PHP specific or also used in other frameworks?

Comment: This is specific for the framework, I've seen it in others frameworks too, but this is not specific for PHP